# JOOQ: is it possible to map one record to multiple tables with same structure?

Tags: mapping, record, jooq, multiple-table-inheritance

I may have three tables App_A, App_B, and App_C. they have the same structure (column names) and they will change together(eg. renaming/adding columns). The reason for having different tables for the same structure is mainly because they represents different products and may scale differently.

Some mentioned to use Super Class in Hibernate/JPA to model this.

Is there a recommended way of doing it in JOOQ?

Comment: With the jOOQ code generator, not that I know of. But you can define your own DTO class and use that instead of the generated entity classes.